# SQL query on AB-->C

Tags: sql, schema, database-schema

Consider a relation S with attributes A , B , C , and D .  Write an SQL query that returns an empty answer if and only if the functional dependency AB-->C holds on relation S .  (It is not important what your query returns when the functional dependency does not hold on S , as long as the query result is not empty in this case.)  Assume that no NULL values are present.

My question is how to return an empty answer and how to correct my part if it's wrong.

```
Select
From S AS S1, S As S2,
Where (S1.C!=S2.C) AND (S1.A=S2.A) AND (S1.B=S2.B)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow does not exist to do your homework.

Comment: What? I am studying for an exam. This is not hw question.

Comment: Plus, this is mid May. School is over, except for finals. Why would I ask a hw question now? This is from a study guide.

Answer (score 0):

... iff *each* value of (a,b) is associated with exactly *one* value of (c).

The check that is needed is whether there are any value of the tuple (a,b) that are related to *more than one* value of *c*.

To demonstrate that the functional dependency does not hold, we would need to demonstrate a counterexample.

Here are a couple of simple examples.

Functional dependency **(a,b)->(c)** holds

```
 a   b   c   d
--  --  --  --  
 2   3   5  42
 2   3   5  42
```

Functional dependency does *not* hold

```
 a   b   c   d
--  --  --  --  
 2   3   7  42
 2   3  11  42
```

If the functional dependency does not hold, that requires that the *same* value of (a,b) correspond to *different* values of (c).

Several queries are possible. Here is one example:

```
 SELECT s.a
      , s.b
   FROM s
  GROUP
     BY s.a
      , s.b
 HAVING NOT ( MIN(s.c) <=> MAX(s.c) )
```